# Why is E[X|F] > 0 a.s. when x is strictly positive?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be an almost surely positive random variable (i.e. $X > 0$ a.s.) defined on the probability space $\big(\Omega,\mathcal G, \mathsf P\big)$.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a sub σ-algebra of $\mathcal G$, then $Y = \mathsf E[X\mid\mathcal F] > 0$ a.s.

Can anyone explain why this is right?

Comment: Is the statement in your question (rather than title) true? Suppose $X$ is a non-negative exponentially random variable with density $e^{-x}$ for $x \ge 0$, so $\Pr(X \gt 0)=1$.  Now take $\mathcal F$ to be restricted to cases where $X=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=\{Y=0\}$. Observe that $B$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable. Invoke the definition of conditional expectation:
$$
\Bbb E[X\cdot 1_B]=\Bbb E[Y\cdot 1_B]=\Bbb E[0\cdot 1_B]=0.
$$
Now ask yourself "How can it happen that $\Bbb E[X\cdot 1_B]=0$ and yet $\Bbb P[X>0]=1$?".

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if i am wrong. so you are claiming that P(B) = 0 and thus Y!=0 a.s.

Comment: And because Y is a conditional expectation, Y is F-measurable and {Y=0} $\in F$. And this is why we can invoke the conditional expectation formula. Is this right?

Comment: "Yes" to your conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a result that says that if a measurable function $f>0$ a.e., then $$\int f>0.$$ Since for all $F\in \mathcal F$, you have that $X\boldsymbol 1_F>0$ almost surely, you get your result.

Comment: how to write E[X|F] as an integral?